# Accessing a method of element inside a callback of listener for a node inside the same element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors, polymer

I am having issues accessing a method inside a dom in the callback of a node that I've attached a click listener to and I can't figure out why. I have tried the followings.

Here's the piece of code responsible to accessing the method inside callback:

```
<dom-module id="my-view2">
  <template>

  ...html codes ... 

  </template> 

  <script> 
  Polymer({
    is: 'my-view2',

    ... properties, etc ...


 //******* trying to access a method *******************
   handleClick: function(e) {
     var btn = document.createElement("paper-button");
     btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
     var el = Polymer.dom(this).querySelector('#my-view2'); 
     el.methodToAccess();
   });
   }

  methodToAccess: function() {
    console.log('success'); 
  },

 });
```

I have tried all of these:

```
this.$$('#my-view2")
document.querySelector("#my-view2"); 
Polymer.dom(this.root).querySelector('#my-view2');
Polymer.dom(this).querySelector('#my-view2');
this.getElementById('my-view2');
```

none of them works and all result in Cannot read property 'methodToAccess' of null. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you bind the callback function to the current `this` scope, you will have direct access to `methodToAccess`.

```
handleClick: function(e) {
 var btn = document.createElement("paper-button");
 btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
   this.methodToAccess();
 }.bind(this));
}
```

That being said you may want to do it the polymer way using [imperative add/remove listeners](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/events):

```
this.listen(this.$.myButton, 'tap', 'onTap');
this.unlisten(this.$.myButton, 'tap', 'onTap');
```

HTH